# Relative layout : align view horizontal and vertical center to other views

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, vertical-alignment, android-constraintlayout, android-relativelayout

I want to create a layout as below
[image]
 Where the dot is center aligned with the text above. And a line is present between two dots

I have tried this

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal">

    <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Place Order" />

        <TextView android:text="Go to Collect"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <TextView android:text="Collect Order"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView android:src="@drawable/dot_one"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <ImageView android:src="@drawable/line_one"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <ImageView android:src="@drawable/dot_two"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <ImageView android:src="@drawable/line_two"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <ImageView android:src="@drawable/dot_three"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

This is making the dots start exactly as the text begins.And not center aligned
[image]

I want to make the dots center align with the text. Tried the same with RelativeLayout. But again I am facing the same issue

Answer (score 1):

Best way is to use the [ConstraintLayout](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/).

Add it to your app module dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    [...]
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
}
```

Then create e.g. LinearLayout for text parts elements each with a weight of 1.
Then for the lower part use a ContraintLayout with Guidelines at 33% and 66% and put the lines between the points using contraints. Your code should then look somewhat like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Place Order" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Go to Collect" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Collect Order" />
</LinearLayout>

<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline33"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.33" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline66"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.66" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/dot1"
        android:layout_width="10dp"
        android:layout_height="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/circle_orange"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/guideline33" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/dot2"
        android:layout_width="10dp"
        android:layout_height="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/circle_orange"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/guideline33"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/guideline66" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/dot3"
        android:layout_width="10dp"
        android:layout_height="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/circle_orange"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/guideline66"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="4dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/square_orange"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/dot1"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/dot2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="4dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/square_orange"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/dot2"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/dot3"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

where the Dot and Square are shape drawables:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="#FF9800" />
</shape>
```

and

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">
    <solid android:color="@color/hek_orange" />
</shape>
```

This gives you this:

[image]

Play with the margins at your own discretion to create enough space between top and lower part and dots and lines.

Comment: Thank you. This helped a lot.

Answer (score 0):

you should use ConstraintLayout. in ConstraintLayout, you specify dot as

```
constraint_leftToLeftOf = R.id.text
constraint_rightToRightOf = R.id.text
```

then it is aligned to the center of the text.

ConstraintLayout:
https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/